# python Pandas: VLOOKUP multiple cells on column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with next task: I would like to identify using pandas (or any other tool on python) if any of multiple cells (Fruit 1 through Fruit 3) in each row from Table 2 contains in column Fruits of Table1. And at the end obtain "Contains Fruits Table 2?" table.

| **Fruits** |
| --- |
| apple |
| orange |
| grape |
| melon |

| Name | Fruit 1 | Fruit 2 | Fruit 3 | Contains Fruits Table 2? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | apple |  |  | Yes |
| Bob | peach | pear | orange | Yes |
| Jack | banana |  |  | No |
| Rob | peach | banana |  | No |
| Rita | apple | orange | banana | Yes |

Fruits in Table 2 can be up to 40 columns. Number of rows in Table1 is about 300.

I hope it is understandable, and someone can help me resolve this.

I really appreciate the support in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. `filter` DataFrame to include columns that contain the word "Fruit"
2. Use `isin` to check if the values are in `table1["Fruits"]`
3. Return True if `any` of fruits are found
4. `map` True/False to "Yes"/"No"

```
table2["Contains Fruits Table 2"] = table2.filter(like="Fruit")
                                          .isin(table1["Fruits"].tolist())
                                          .any(axis=1)
                                          .map({True: "Yes", False: "No"})

>>> table2

   Name Fruit 1 Fruit 2 Fruit 3 Contains Fruits Table 2
0  Mike   apple    None    None                     Yes
1   Bob   peach    pear  orange                     Yes
2  Jack  banana    None    None                      No
3   Rob   peach  banana    None                      No
4  Rita   apple  orange  banana                     Yes
​~~~
```

Comment: You don't need `apply`, DataFrames have also an 'isin' method. You can do `.isin(table1['Fruits'].to_numpy())` instead.

Comment: Upvoted, but `to_numpy()` or `tolist()` is required, otherwise the match will be done by index alignment ;)

Comment: Correct again @HarryPlotter :)

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much!